# Datasource query limit is different of page size

Tags: google-app-maker

In AppMaker I have a calculated datasource and I've set its page size to 10.

In the function I call to return the records (`queryRecords`), the `limit` parameter is set to 11 (I don't change it on front side).

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good catch. App Maker sets the limit to page size + 1 on all queries because it needs to look ahead to see if there are more pages or not (this allows us to fill in the "lastPage" property because we looked one ahead and found a record). But for calculated data sources this is pretty confusing, I'll file a bug to look into this. At the very least it needs some clear documentation.

I think if you did try to return 11 records, it should only show 10 on the client, and fill in the last page property appropriately.